# Startando começa com "S" ou com "E" ou nem deveria ser utilizada?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, estrangeirismos

Acho que todos sabem o que é estrangeirismo, mas só pra garantir: estrangeirismo é o abrasileiramento de palavras estrangeiras, não apenas o uso delas, por exemplo: "startando".

E minha pergunta é exatamente sobre "startando", depois de uma pequena e cômica (quase séria) conversa de almoço:

Startando começa com "S" ou com "E" ou nem deveria ser utilizada ?

O tom quase sério da conversa é o fato de termos documentos da empresa com essa palavra.

Comment: Já inventaram inicializar pra isso.

Comment: @CarlosMartins A pergunta é pertinente à lingua portuguesa, e certamente tem algum sentido didático. Caso contrário, não haveria documentos da empresa utilizando o termo. Já estive em uma ou duas _startups_ e este tipo de vocabulário é bastante comum, infelizmente.

Comment: É uma boa conversa entre amigos mas como não faz parte do vocabulário não considero relevante. Existe um sem número de palavras a utilizar como sinónimos. principiar, criar, estabelecer, instaurar, instituir, introduzir, entabular, desencadear,   preludiar, originar, partir, despertar, formar, fundar,  lançar.

Comment: Estrangeirismos não é abrasileiramento, mas absorção de termos estrangeiros de qualquer língua para com qualquer outra. Já li em algum lugar que o inglês por exemplo é composto de uns 40% de estrangeirismos, a maioria do frances, e pra piorar originalmente eles raramente rescrevem os termos com seus fonemas, a grafia costuma ficar como a da lingua origem exemplos: Façade, naïve, coöperate,...

Answer (score 4):

Sugiro adotar apenas a gramática oficial do brasil em documentos corporativos.

Sobre a pergunta em si, como a palavra não existe, sua definição formal também não existe.

Como o anglicismo é mania de brasileiro, startar e estartar existem.

http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/startar/

http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/estartar/

Comment: Utilize ou use: iniciando, inicializando, começando, carregando, entrando em funcionamento,

Comment: Para ser sincero, existe um contexto - muito específico - em que o uso deste termo é até preferencial: em jogos online de estratégia em tempo real, _startar_ significa "comprometer-se com a batalha, forçar o confronto". Mas parece algo muito distante do contexto da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Prefiro dividir as derivações de "start" em dois:

1) **Startup**: Usado largamente no Brasil pelo noticiário de tecnologia e corporativo. Portanto, já não faltam mais motivos para ser uma palavra que comece a constar em documentos e contratos privados. Nunca vi, mas não tenho dúvidas que já seja usada em documentos e contratos privados, até mesmo porque não temos uma tradução perfeita e nem conseguiremos convencer o público e os noticiários de mudar isso.

Há alguns anos usávamos "empresa ou projeto embrionário", ou ainda "negócio iniciante".

2) **Startar**: Esse aqui já não comunica muita coisa. Não consta nos noticiários. Não me parece um palavra largamente usada, pelo menos no Brasil. Portanto, estrangeirismo vazio de sentido para a maioria das pessoas. **Não use!** Dizer "iniciar" ou "começar" comunica muito mais do que "startar".

As línguas evoluem e termos são ao longo do tempo absorvidos entre elas. E a língua corrente do dia-a-dia é a que costuma se tornar, após um tempo - muito - a oficial, em detrimento da formal na sua respectiva época passada.

Um exemplo é o estrangeirismo **deletar** do inglês "to delete" que foi introduzido na língua falada e escrita informalmente na década de 80, no Brasil. E cerca de 1 década depois, não lembro o tempo exato, passou a constar nos dicionários.

Em tecnologia fazemos brincadeiras, aportuguesando certos termos, ficam engraçados, é divertido, mas tome cuidado, mantenha-os restrito ao contexto ou a organização/grupo onde ele faz sentido. De algumas centenas, vou listar alguns que me lembro agora:

- **Mallocar**, Exemplo: "Se mallocou, então tá mallocado". Vem do nome de uma função de uma linguagem de programação chamada C. A função em questão é a "malloc".
- **Printar**, do inglês "to print", na tradução literal: imprimir.
- **Printifar**, do nome de uma função da linguagem C "printf".
- **Estepinto**, do inglês "step into". Exemplo: "dá um estepinto aqui nessa função".
- **Breca point**, do Inglês "break point". Exemplo: "ali tem um breca point"; "Brecou no ponto certo de debug"?
- **Cezeiro**: Programador de linguagem C.
- **Javeiro**: Programador de linguagem Java.
- **Tarar**: Do nome de um comando Unix chamado "tar". Exemplo: "Tarou todos os arquivos?", "Tá tudo tarado".
- **Grepar**: Do nome de um comando Unix chamado "grep". Exemplo: "Grepa direito. Tá grepando errado, por isso não filtra direito"

Há uma série de termos corriqueiros, criados tanto no inglês quanto em português, embora no nosso caso sejam absorvidos ou adaptados do inglês, pois foram criados primeiro no inglês:

- Clicar.
- Cliqueiro: Alguém que só sabe usar o computador por meio de cliques.
- Tap: Termos da era do "touch screen": Tocar, Bater, apertar.
- Bipar: Emitir um ruido sonoro: Beep
- Scripteiro: Alguém que sabe ou prefere usar o computador por meio de linha de comandos ou scripts.
- Debugar: Depurar, ou remover bichos (bugs)
- Bugar: Bichar, algo com bicho. Um programa bichado, ou seja estragado, com defeito. Hoje está sendo usado no Brasil pelos jovens para qualquer coisa onde há algum tipo de falha ou anormalidade, um comportamento fora do esperado inclusive no comportamento humano. Exemplo: O cara vascilou e caiu: "O cara bugou"